# How to draw points,lines and get coordinates in canvas in PLT scheme?

Tags: racket

I am newbie in PLT scheme (using DrScheme). So, this question may be annoying to many developers.

I want to draw points in every click (mouse event) in a canvas and get the coordinate of that point. Also I want to draw a line from the last point to the last mouse event point.

As per documentation, they suggested to use world.ss (instead of draw.ss) from teachpack. But I am not getting it how to do that.

Now how will I do that? Any suggestion or hints are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in writing such programs, and especially if you're new to Scheme, then have a look at the new [How to Design Worlds](http://world.cs.brown.edu/) book.